# How To Limit The Times a User Could Input

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm a beginner Making a Game Where The Program Generates a random Number And The User Needs To Guess The Number. If They Fail 5 Times They Lose. I Need To Count How Many Times The User Can Enter And If It Reaches 5 And Print You Lost And restart.

Something Like This

```
cnt = 0 
if cnt >= 5:
   print("You Lost")
   pass
```

Comment: You will need to use a `for` loop on the cnt variable

Comment: Sorry. Can You Show Me a Example?

Answer (score 0):

You need :

```
import random

op_number = random.randint(1,20)
# print(op_number)

number = int(input("Guess a number between 1 to 20 : ")) 
count=0
while True:
    if count == 5:
        print("You Lose.")
        break
    count+=1
    if op_number == number:
        print("You won")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect guess. {} attempts left.".format(5-count))

    number = int(input("Guess a number between 1 to 20 : "))
```